# Nonsingular Cubic Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let consider a nonsingular cubic surface on $\mathbb{P}^3$, $S=\mathcal{V}(G)$, where G is an homogeneous polynomial of degree 3.

I want to prove that S does not contain three not coplanar concurrent lines.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it's true ?

Comment: @N.H.: it is true.

Comment: Hint: Suppose there were three such lines; think about the tangent space to $S$ at the point where the three lines intersect.

Comment: Thanks @bertram, it holds using the tangent space.